Integral graded algebra of finite type is approximable
The following is the definition of approximable algebra.
An integral graded $K$-algebra $\oplus_{n\geqslant 0}B_n$ is said to be approximable if
1.$$rk_K(B_n)<+\infty,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, $$and $$\exists N, s.t. \forall n>N, B_n\neq 0. $$
2.$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists p_0 \in \mathbb{N}, s.t. \forall p>p_0, \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{rk_K(Im(S^nB_p\rightarrow B_{np}))}{rk_K(B_{np})}>1-\epsilon. $$
The symbol $S^nB_p$ means the $n$-symmetric power of $B_p$, then these image components construct a graded subalgebra of $B$ generated by $B_p$ over $B_0$.
Now if $B$ is an integral graded $K$-algebra of finite type over $K$, is $B$ approximable?
The condition $\dim_K B_0<+\infty$ implies that $B_0$ is a field and further a finite extension over $K$ by Hilbert Nullstellensatz, so to solve this problem, it is OK to just assume that $B_0=K$.
I have found a reference using Newton-Okounkov body, but does there exist a simple verification?
